# How to display data from database by getting inputs from user in php mqsql?

Tags: php, mysql

How to display data from database by user specified date range and also comparing user input value with database field value.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date between '".$date_min"' AND '".date_max"'";
```

assuming $date_min and $date_max are the values of your user input, and table the DB table where you want to query.

The php will be something like:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date between '".$date_min"' AND '".date_max"'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Provided you made the part for user input.

These is from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp.

Some research before making a question is required.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Now, you could try something like this, using an ajax request (jQuery required):

JS:

```
/**
 * Created by evochrome on 26-3-2016.
 */
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var timer;
    $('#reset').click(function(e) {
        $('input').val(""); //set value equal to zero
    });
    $('input').on("input", function (e) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(getTableContents,2000);//Execute function `getTableContents` after 3s
    });

});

function getTableContents() {
    $('td').fadeOut(500, function(){ $(this).parent().remove();});
    setTimeout(function() {
        var inputs = {};
        $(".theader input").each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() != '') {
                inputs[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
            }
        });
        $.ajax({ //ajax request
            method: "POST",
            url: "../php/fetch.php",
            data: inputs,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var tmpObject = {};
                var i = 0;

                data.forEach(function (row) {
                    var obj = data[i];
                    $('table').append("<tr id='t" + i + "'></tr>");
                    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
                        $('#t' + i).append("<td style='display: none;'>" + row[key] + "</td>");
                    });
                    i++
                });
                $('td').fadeIn(500);


            }
        })
    }, 500);
}
```

CSS:

```
table {
    width: 80%;
}
td {
    width: 40%;
    background-color:green;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}


.theader{
    width:100%;
    justify-content:space-around;
    display:flex;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>T-Test</title>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Input Some Data</h1>
    <div class="theader">
        <input name="FromDate" type="date"/>
        <input name="ToDate" type="date"/>
        <button id="reset">Reset</button>
    </div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Appleseed</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
/**
 * Creator: evochrome
 * Date: 26-3-2016
 * Time: 15:40
 */

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', $db_name, $db_password, $db_user);
if (! $conn){
    echo 'Oh damn a crash!';
    die(' Connection failed :(');
}

$fields = array(
    'FromDate', 'ToDate'
);

$where = "1=1"; //true
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if ($value = $_POST[$field]) {
        $where .= " AND $field = '$value'"; //for each field add clause
    }
}
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE $where"); //insert tablename and where clause
$array = array();
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ //fetch from db
    $array[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($array);
$query->close();
$conn->close();
```